# Probability never an equal number of black & white balls drawn is ${{m - n}\over{m + n}}$

Tags: probability, combinatorics

Here's a question from my probability textbook:

> A bag contains $m$ black balls and $n$ white balls ($m > n$). These are drawn out in succession. Show that the chance that there shall never be an equal number of black and white balls drawn is ${{m - n}\over{m + n}}$.

I tried inducting, but that was a total mess with lots of nested paretheses to account for the branching off at each turn.

Another approach is to interpret this is to start at $(m, n)$ and move either down or left one unit each turn - what's the probability your path to $(0, 0)$ is always above/to the left of $y = x + n - m$? But I'm not sure how to proceed solving the problem with that interpretation, any help would be well-appreciated.

Comment: It is the classical [Bertrand's ballot theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bertrand%27s_ballot_theorem)

Comment: Induction should have led you to the answer. In fact the page linked by Jean Marie has proof by induction too.